# List with two different object need to sort

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

ArrayList has two different class /objects

```
   - Student class has 2 fields --> NAME and ID

   - Employee class has 2 fields --> NAME and ID
```

need to sort based on **ID field**. Could you please help me on this thanks.

My suggestion is to use comparator could please help me on java code.

```
class Emp {
  String name;
  int number;
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public int getNumber() { return number; }
  public void setNumber(int number) { this.number = number; }
}

class Student {
  String name;
  int number;
  public String getName() { return name; }
  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public int getNumber() { return number; }
  public void setNumber(int number) { this.number = number; }
}

class empcomparator implements Comparator {
  @Override
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
   String a = ((emp) o1).getName();
   String b = ((student) o2).getName();
   return a.compareTo(b); return 1;
  }
}
```

main class my code:

```
Emp emp = new Emp();
emp.setName("test1");
emp.setNumber(11);
Student stud= new Student ();
stud.setName("test2");
stud.setNumber(22);
List<Object> studentlist = new ArrayList<Object>();
studentlist.add(emp);
studentlist.add(stud);
Collections.sort(studentlist, new empcomparator());
```

List contain 100 object like this need to sort based on id. Please suggest me nice idea.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be advised that StackOverflow is not a "write my code" service. If you are in need of help, please post the code you have written so we may assist you appropriately.

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have done thus far.

Comment: suggest me how to implement same in java

Comment: Are you familier with oop concepts??

Comment: i  know oops concepts i face this question so need clarrification. if understood explain here other do your work - @JanithaMadushan

Comment: @JanithaMadushan - I know opps concept understand my question properly

Answer (score 3):

Make a `Person` class with name and ID fields.

Create the `Student` and `Employee` class so that they inherit from the `Person` class.

Then you can make an `ArrayList<Person>` which can contain both elements and you can sort it using a `Comparator<Person>`.

Modifying your code:

```
abstract class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    String name;
    int number;
    public Person( final int id, final String name ){
        setNumber( id );
        setName( name );
    }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int getNumber() { return number; }
    public void setNumber(int number) { this.number = number; }
    public int compareTo( final Person otherPerson ){
      return Integer.compare( this.getNumber(), otherPerson.getNumber() );
    }
    public abstract String toString();
}

class Emp extends Person {
    public Emp( final int id, final String name ){
        super( id, name );
    }
    public String toString(){ return String.format( "Employee: %d, %s", getNumber(), getName() ); }
}

class Student extends Person {
    public Student( final int id, final String name ){
        super( id, name );
    }
    public String toString(){ return String.format( "Student: %d, %s", getNumber(), getName() ); }
}

public static void main( final String[] args ){
    ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
    people.add( new Student( 23, "Bob" ) );
    people.add( new Emp( 12, "Alice" ) );
    people.add( new Student( 3, "Carol" ) );
    people.add( new Emp( 5, "Denise" ) );
    System.out.println( people.toString() );
    Collections.sort( people );
    System.out.println( people.toString() );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your example. my requirement is class emp { String name; int id; getter setter }  and class student{ String name, int id getter and setter }.     array list has these two class with 100 size. need to sort based on id field.

Comment: Both `Emp` and `Student` classes have **all** those fields and methods - they inherit them from `Person`. The ArrayList can have as many people in it as you want and if you run it then you will see that it does indeed sort them by ID - using the `Person` class's `Comparable` interface to do the sort.